# jQuery problem, jQuery takes over all links on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#results").load( "jquery-routing.php", { pageNo: $(this).text(), sortBy: $("#sortBy").val()} );
        return false;
    });
});    
</script> 

  <div id="results"> </div>    
<a href="jquery-routing.php?p=1">1</a>
<a href="jquery-routing.php?p=2">2</a>
```

that code works fine, only problem that after I run it all my a href links stop to work! The links become jquery ajax calls.. why?

Comment: If your intention is to execute this load() whenever any link is clicked, then Lyon is right; otherwise, everyone else is right :)  (probably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target specific links, use the id or class tag on your anchor tags.
E.g.

```
<a class="link1" href=""></a>
<a id="link2" href-""></a>
```

Do note that id tags are unique within a page and can only be used once.
Reference those links in jQuery using:

```
$('a.link1').click(function() {}
$('#link2').click(function() {}
```

or you can combine both:

```
$('a.link1, #link2').click(function() {}
```

What you need to do is assign an id or class tag to the link that will call the ajax request. E.g. `<a class="ajax" href="">ajax</a>` and referencing it with `$('a.ajax').click(function () {}`

Comment: That's needed to override the default link following behaviour with the desired ajax call instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're `$("a")` selector matches all `<a ...>` tags, you need to change it to something more specific:

```
$("a#someid")
$("a.someclass")
$("div#somecontainer a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the onclick event of all anchor tags on the page.  Try only selecting the link that you want instead of the more general $("a")

Answer (score 0):

Your selector $("a") indicates all the hiperlink in your page.

You may need to give a specific id to the hiperlink where you want your ajax call to work and then change the selector based on that.

ex:

```
<a id= "my-link" href="" >ddd</a>

$("a#my-link").click()
```

Comment: ok, that worked well!

<a id="paginator">1</a>

how do I make it load the first page by default?

Comment: I think classes will be a better idea than Id since he has multiple hyperlinks